# Append custom attributes to nested fields in JSON response on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my application, I have the following code inside my Controller:

```
def show
    @ratings = Rating.where(event_id: params[:id]).order(created_at: :desc)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @ratings.to_json(include: :app_user) }
    end
  end
```

That returns to me a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "app_user_id": 2,
    "event_id": 17,
    "comentario": "Comment 1",
    "nota": 10,
    "created_at": "2017-02-22T13:50:40.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22T13:50:40.000Z",
    "app_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "facebook_id": "1343401692386568",
      "created_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "app_user_id": 2,
    "event_id": 17,
    "comentario": "Comment 2",
    "nota": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "app_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "facebook_id": "1343401692386568",
      "created_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z"
    }
  },
]
```

How do I add a custom attribute to the **app_user** section of each of the items? For example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "app_user_id": 2,
    "event_id": 17,
    "comentario": "Comment 1",
    "nota": 10,
    "created_at": "2017-02-22T13:50:40.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22T13:50:40.000Z",
    "app_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "facebook_id": "1343401692386568",
      "created_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "custom_attr1": "value1",
      "custom_attr2": "value2",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "app_user_id": 2,
    "event_id": 17,
    "comentario": "Comment 2",
    "nota": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "app_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "facebook_id": "1343401692386568",
      "created_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "custom_attr1": "value1",
      "custom_attr2": "value2",
    }
  },
]
```

The custom attributes *WILL BE* different based on each **app_user id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not tied to the flat structure, you may do the following:

```
class AppUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def custom_attributes
    # custom attributes different for each app_user
    # return anything you want
    { attr1: "value1", attr2: "value2" }
  end
end

# controller
format.json { render json: @ratings.to_json(include: { app_user: { methods: :custom_attributes}}) }
```

This will give the next output:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "app_user_id": 2,
    "event_id": 17,
    "comentario": "Comment 2",
    "nota": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22T13:29:56.000Z",
    "app_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "facebook_id": "1343401692386568",
      "created_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-09T18:36:01.000Z",
      "custom_attributes": {
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can I return more than one value in the **custom_attributes** function so the result JSON should be `"custom_attributes": { attr1: value1, attr2: value2}`?

Comment: @AlexandreSottanideCarvalho yes, if you return hash from `custom_attributes` method